Why is mononitration of phenol carried out at low temperatures?
This is NileRed's video on the mononitration of phenol. He does it using the standard textbook way of using $\ce{H2SO4}$ to produce a nitronium ($\ce{NO2+}$) ion from $\ce{NaNO3}$ (or just $\ce{HNO3}$). He does all of this within an ice bath, maintaining a temperature of under $\pu{20^\circ C}$ for the reaction.
I don't quite understand what the ice bath is supposed to do. I tried to find it on the internet, and all I've managed to find is that it prevents $\ce{NO2}$ from escaping. The reaction seems to be an exothermic one that releases large amounts of gas if not done in an ice bath. But I don't understand why this is so...
Also, how does he prevent further nitration of phenol. I'm guessing that the temperature control also somehow prevents di or tri substitutions from occurring, but I don't understand that either. Could someone please explain what exactly the ice bath is there for in the reaction.

Increasing temperature will increase reaction rates, because there are more collisions. This means an already reactive molecule like phenol (or any activated aromatic ring system) will react with whatever electrophile's around. This applies to mononitrophenol as well, which—even though it has an electron withdrawing nitro group on it—is still more activated than benzene. Generally over-nitration can be prevented by using just dilute (around 30%) nitric acid.

The first step in the nitration with $\ce{HNO3}$ is the generation of the nitronium cation, $\ce{^+NO2}$, under elimination of water

The source of protons to drive this sequence of equilibria to the right is the addition of $\ce{H2SO4}$.  Mono in mononitration however already hints that phenols are electron rich* aromatic compounds (i.e. much of electron density by the planar circular array of $\pi$ electrons distributed among the non-H atoms of the aromatic cycle) so that either a high concentration of $\ce{^+NO2}$ cations, as well as an elevated reaction temperature can drive the reaction forward to yield the product of double alkylation, as well as products by oxidation.  Note, the author of the video states the potential pitfall of polynitration within the first minute.
In addition to this, remember the preferential orientation of a second substituent entering a benzene decorated with an electron donating substituent (as e.g., $\ce{C6H5-OH}$ of phenols) is ortho and para (in 1,2 or 1,4 relationship) relative to the already present substituent.  In addition to prevent a thermal run-off, moderation of temperature typically allows to prefer the formation of the thermodynamically more stable product; normally, this were the p-addition, but this countered by the presence of two reaction sites for the o-addition.  The author of the video equally shows this within the first minute of the video, too.

* The lower the $\pi$ electron density (for instance by presence of an  electron withdrawing, desactivating group), the lower the chance for more than one nitration.  From a practical point of view (and somewhat in contrast to the author's description), it is better to use only diluted nitric acid (instead of concentrated one) with a bit of sulfuric acid (for the above mentioned generation of the nitronium cation).  The slow addition of the aqueous phenol solution to the cooled solution of the nitration agent, as displayed in the video then again is well in line for the nitration of electron rich aromatic compounds.

Both @Sonder 's comment and your answer say that the temperature is kept low to prevent further nitration of phenol. However, this resource given in the description of the same video, at the end of the third paragraph under the section titled 'reaction', says that the temperature must be kept low to prevent nitrous fumes from developing. Well, to me at least, the two statements seem to be at odds with each other as one says, temperature control is to prevent nitrogen from escaping, and the other, to prevent it from attaching.

@Ekarshi 1) there is a difference between nitrous/nitrogen gas and the nitronium cation. They want to limit nitrous fumes because they're dangerous. 2) the nitronium electrophile produced will obviously collide and react with more molecules of mononitrophenol if the temperature is higher. The low temperature is to limit this from happening, so a greater proportion of species in the system are mononitrophenol. Some minute dinitrophenol will still be made, even at low temperatures.

@Ekarshi Nitrogen ($\ce{N#N}$) is not an active ingredient in the reaction. It is present because the reaction is run open air. At reaction conditions, nitrous fumes of $\ce{NO}$ (colorless) and $\ce{NO2}$ (yellow/orange; the two in equilibrium with each other) do not from from $\ce{N2}$ (because of the triple bond), but possibly from $\ce{^+NO2}$ (e.g., dehydration of $\ce{HNO3}$ by $\ce{H2SO4}$ via $\ce{N2O5}$ in local hot spots). The higher the temperature, the more likely these side reactions run concurrently; overall, less yield of the wanted nitrated product and more harmful waste.

@Ekarshi Often, a black tar/gooey raw product (like the raw product of p-nitrophenol shown) indicates a reaction did no run cleanly, a temperature to high (for too long) or/and polymerization/oxydations equally occurred. Like running a Friedel-Crafts acylation with acetyl chloride with electron rich pyrrole likely would go bad because of too high reactivity in the flask. i) Selection of reagents, ii) their concentration, iii) sequence and rate of addition, iv) temperature control/management, v) efficient stirring, vi) scale etc are among the parameters to consider to set up a reaction.

The mononitration of phenol needs to be carried out at low temperatures, mainly to control the rate and selectivity of the reaction. Here are a few specific reasons:
Control the reaction rate: The hydroxyl group (-OH) in phenol is an active group with a strong activation effect, making the benzene ring more susceptible to nitration. If the reaction temperature is too high, the reaction will be too violent and difficult to control.
Avoid polynitration: At higher temperatures, phenol is not only prone to mononitration, but also more prone to polynitration (i.e., forming dinitro or trinitrophenol). By lowering the temperature, the reaction can more effectively and selectively generate mononitrophenol and reduce the generation of polynitro products.
Improve product selectivity: Under low temperature conditions, the nitro group preferentially directs to the ortho or para position of phenol, thereby obtaining the desired o-nitrophenol or p-nitrophenol. Excessive temperature will lead to changes in product distribution and increase the generation of by-products.
Therefore, the mononitration of phenol is generally carried out at low temperatures below 0°C to ensure that the reaction is mild, controllable, and highly selective mononitro products are obtained.

This post has been flagged as likely being an AI product. AI-generated content is not permitted on Chemistry SE. A repeat offense will result in a ban.
